# Bluetooth Dial up Networking Profile in KitKat

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working in Kitkat Bluedroid stack to develop a Dial Up networking profile ( only DT Role). So far, I am able to search a Dialup GW server, and successfully connected to the remote GW.(RFCOMM Connection).  Now the use-case is to initiate a PPP session, so that I can browse Internet web pages over Bluetooth. I would like to know.

1- I have located a PPP implementation in Kitkat. So, I the usecase of initiating a PPP session and browse internet web pages over DUN Bluetooth link is feasible. is it a correct understanding for Kitkat, bluedroid stack. ?

2- The RFCOMM_CreateConnection returns a connection handle. How do I bind this handle to a virtual com port ?. so that, the data from the browser will reach rfcomm directly.

3- I am quite new to ANdroid. In Windows/windows ce, the Ras API/Connection Manager APIs are used to trigger a PPP session (instance RasDial()). How the PPP session establishment is achieved in Android ?

Kindly help and share your suggestions.

Thanks,
Siya Chin.

Answer (score 0):

bluedroid stack does not give a standard serial interface. 
therefore, legacy serial applications can not run over a virtual serial port.